# upload image and video

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, id3

I have a web site that is created in flash.There is a link for upload images and videos .I want to create this uploading module for this link.There is also a requirement that the images and videos which is upload to the user created folders or albums like orkut image uploading.The video should be maximum 5-6 minutes.

I want a brief answer for this problem ,because i am a new comer in web application.If any one can please help me.
Thank You..

Comment: You'll need to provide the type of programming languages/platforms you will be using or you have the know-how.

Comment: i am using asp.net and sql server

Answer (score 1):

If you're fresh to this you will need to decide on some server-side technology.  Probably in your case I'd recommend taking a look at PHP (it's possible your host already supports this).  Google 'PHP file upload', there are plently of tutorials.  The fact that your website is in flash with complicate things a little bit though.

*UPDATE*

I've just read your comment re ASP.NET (woudl have helped if you'd included this in the question).  So in this case google 'ASP.NET file upload'.

Answer (score 1):

**upload module client**

Take a look into Flex [FileReferenceList](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/FileReferenceList.html) to sort out how to upload files using Flex/Flash.

**upload module server**

You will then require some server logic to save the file, this can be done in a multitude of ways but as you are using ASP take a look at [`CopyFile`](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_copyfile.asp). Were you using PHP server you would use something like [`copy`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php).

**length of video - size versus time**
You really can't get hold of the video lenght until the user has uploaded the whole file. Thus it's generally more interesting to limit the upload to a fixed size, say 50Mb. That said you can take a look into [getID3](http://www.getid3.org) that will be able to read a lot of info about the uploaded file (once it's uploaded). You could then use that to limite the size.

Just one last note. The thing your trying to achieve is a fairly complex task and, as you say, you are new to web-development. If your feeling overwhelmed by the whole thing try to split it into very tiny projects and work them up one after the other.

Hope it helps!